# Is it possible to use Panda3D inside a wxPython app?

Tags: python, 3d, wxpython

I'm developing a wxPython application. Will it be possible to embed a 3D animation controlled by Panda3D inside the gui?

Bonus question: Do you think that Panda3D is the best choice? (My interest is physical simulations, and no, I don't need an engine that supports Physics, my program is responsible for calculating the physics, I just need an engine to show it well.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - the Panda3D wiki has a mention of [using wxPython to handle GUI duties](http://www.panda3d.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Loop).

There's also some threads on the Panda3D forum ([1](http://www.panda3d.org/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?t=2397), [2](http://www.panda3d.org/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?p=43081)) which might help.

Another popular choice for simulation visualization in Python is VPython; it is [also dockable in wx](http://mientki.ruhosting.nl/data_www/pylab_works/pw_vpython_docking.html).